# Pass generic Hashable in FocusState

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, ios15

I've a View and I would like to put it in my public package.

this MyTextField is designed for:

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    enum Field: Hashable, CaseIterable {
        case name
        case fullName
        case age
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    .....
```

**MyTextField:**

```
struct MyTextField: View {

    @Binding var text: String
    let systemName: String = ""
    let focusedValue: ContentView2.Field
    
    var focusedField: FocusState<ContentView2.Field?>.Binding
        
    init(text: Binding<String>,  systemName: String, focusedField: FocusState<ContentView2.Field?>.Binding, focusedValue: ContentView2.Field) {
        self._text = text
        self.focusedField = focusedField
        self.focusedValue = focusedValue
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: systemName)
            TextField("Name", text: $text)
                .focused(focusedField, equals: focusedValue)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
    }
}
```

if I try to put generic Hashable as Input, from

`var focusedField: FocusState<ContentView2.Field?>.Binding` to `var focusedField: FocusState<Hashable>.Binding`

I get the error `Protocol 'Hashable' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself`

Comment: `FocusState` is already generic over `Value` which must conform to `Hashable`: `struct FocusState<Value> where Value : Hashable` (`Value has to be a concrete type`). You could specialise your var on an `AnyHashable`, but I don't see the point in doing so in this code.

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
struct MyTextField<value: Hashable>: View {

var focusedField: (binding: FocusState<value?>.Binding, equals: value?)

var body: some View {

        HStack {

            Image(systemName: systemName)
            TextField("Name", text: $text)
                .focused(focusedField.binding,
                          equals: focusedValue.equals)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: For some reason, wrapping my generic focus state in a tuple eliminated my error `Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type`